# When cows fly...?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

In Baba Kama perek Meruba the Gemora quotes an arguement between R' Akiva and the Chachomim concerning whether the airspace of a person's property under the level of his wall is considered like his property. For example the Gemora talks about someone returning another person's animal by throwing it over his wall, and those Tannaim argue about whether the object is acquired before it landed or only when it actually lands. Our shiur was wondering **how do you get a cow over a 50 foot wall?**
On a related note, **is a shor shot from a cowtapult automatically considered moo-ad (warned)?**

### I welcome answers to both questions.

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are you asking about the mechanics of launching a cow over a high wall, or are you asking about the "moo-ad" status of a bovine launched from a "cowtapult"?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya! I would recommend clarifying exactly what you are asking. (For example you could clarify that you are wondering what could cause a cow to fly, and clarify that the second question is "extra credit". That would limit the the post to one clear question.

Comment: Hey, @Askatz200, your name looks familiar; is [this other account](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/14278/akatz2k) also yours? If so, please [ask for them to be merged](/help/merging-accounts). That way, you can keep track of all of your activity here in one place (and then you won't need to get approval from other people to edit your own posts). Welcome to MY, and I hope you enjoy our [tag:purim-torah-in-jest] questions while they're in season! :)

Comment: Are you "shor" that you're asking the right question???

Comment: Ten demerits for really bad puns at the end...;-)

Comment: An African or a European cow?

Answer (score 0):

A drop between two courtyards  is a possibility. There are a thousands of simple possibilities.

But following the Mishna of Shevuot 3, 8, it may be that this was a camel,  not a cow.

Comment: Or at least a bird that he named camel... (I know it's not Purim Torah season, but I know I'll forget that line if I wait until next month.)

Answer (score 0):

The cow is **parah**-chuted from a plane.